# Is anyone using WADL standard for web service?

Tags: web-services

Is anyone using WADL standard for web service? 
If yes what kind of api are you using to host the web service?

Answer (score 1):

Two Implementations are:

1.[Sun Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)

2.[Jboss RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)

Comment: Are those implementations? Or `API`s, as the OP requested?